# Trouble with Javascript namespacing in returning an Array from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call to sharepoint (shown below).

```
function GetProductIDSforActiveQuote() {
var arr = new Array();
$().SPServices({
    operation: "UpdateListItems",
    listName: "Quotes",
    ID:quoteID,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        arr = $(this).attr("ows_Products").split(',');
      });
    }
  });
return arr;
}
```

I'm trying to return an Array, but get an empty array at the end. I can verify by putting a console log inside the completefunc block, that values are being returned properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX calls are asynchronous. This means that by the time you hit the line `return arr`, the `completeFunc` hasn't necessarily been invoked yet.

Could you modify the code so it takes a callback function which is provided the array? Like this:

```
function GetProductIDSforActiveQuote(callback) {
    // other details omitted
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {          
        arr = // your code
        callback(arr); // <- here's the difference.
      };        
}
```

In the callback function, you could then process the array however you needed.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. I can't seem to return the Array inside the completefunc, however. How would I do that?

Comment: Will mark answer in a minute. This function has an async parameter that you can set to false, and it will complete the call before returning the array. Not quite your answer, but you lead me to it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Wesley, that will probably freeze the UI until the response arrives. I'd go with the callback option.

Comment: If I did that, how do I then pass the object back to the original function? Meaning, if I call: var x = GetProductIDSforActiveQuote(), var x cannot access the result of function callback(array)

Comment: @Wesley The asynchronous nature means you pretty much can't.  You would have to restructure your existing code to be given the array, rather than asking for it, and then that function would be the callback you pass in. Depending on how widespread calls to this function are, that could be a big change, or a small one.  Using a callback would be a more "pure" solution than setting that flag to have the function block.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `SPServices` is asynchronous, so it will return before the response arrives. You have to use the array from inside `completefunc`.